# chrome.webrequest.onBeforeRequest and other listeners are not listening on first click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension to record the request data for all the requests fired in chrome. I am using chrome.webRequest api to collect the data.

In extension, I have created a button, on the click of button I have called a function to start recording. There I have added 2 listeners

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(onBeforeRequest, RequestFilter,
         ['requestBody']);
        // We use onSendHeaders to collect send headers
chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener(onSendHeaders, RequestFilter,
            ['requestHeaders']);
```

In onBeforeRequest method, I have added a console.log statement.

When I click the start button for the first time and fire a request it doesn't print the log. After repetitive clicks on the button, it starts working.

What am I doing wrong?

One more thing observed by me is: When I inspect the extension and then click on start recording, it records in first click itself.